# problem in iterating list of dictionaries

Tags: python

i have a list of dictionaries:

```
 data =   [ {"email":"admin@yopmail.com",

        "data": [
            {"content_title": "1", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": "audio"},

            {"content_title": "2", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""},

            {"content_title": "3", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""}
        ]
    }
]
```

so i have to check each data present in data key. and in every dictionaries i have to validate the key and its value. like in "content_type" it should not be empty. so which row doesnt satisfy validation even because of one key value pair, it should be appended to invalidData list. and others in validData list. So my problem is how to iterate that when one wrong value comes there for loop breaks and go for next iteration.

I have succeeded this so far. But it doesnt show right o/p.

```
validData = []
invalidData = []
flag = True
    if emailID is not None: 
        flag = True
        for i in data:
            for q,w in enumerate(i['data']):
                if len(i['data'])>0:
                    if 'content_title' in i['data'][q] and i['data'][q]['content_title'] !="":
                        flag = True
                    else:
                        flag = False
                        continue
                    if "content_type" in i['data'][q] and i['data'][q]["content_type"] != "" and i['data'][q]["content_type"].capitalize() in ['Audio','Video']:
                        flag = True
                    else:
                        flag = False
                        continue
                    if flag == True:
                        validData.append(i['data'][q])
                if flag == False:
                    invalidData.append(i['data'][q])
```

i want this o/p

```
validData = [{"content_title": "1", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": "audio"}]

invalidData = [
    {"content_title": "2", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""},
    {"content_title": "3", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""}
]
```

either my logic is wrong or my approach. please correct me.

this is the o/p i got

```
invalidData []
validData [{'content_title': '1', 'content_status': 'Available', 'content_type': 'audio'}]
```

Comment: What output is shown? Therr are two datas Ou show to us? Are you usinh the right one?

Comment: @niklas o/p i got invalidData []
validData [{'content_title': '1', 'content_status': 'Available', 'content_type': 'audio'}]

Answer (score 0):

Your `flag` will get overrridden. I will hint you in the right direction with the following function:

```
# function that checks if a single dict entry in is valid
def is_data_valid( data ):
    return 'content_title' in data and data['content_title'] is not '' \
        and 'content_type' in data and data['content_type'] is not '' \
        and 'content_status' in data and data['content_status'] is not ''
```

Full Solution ( Spoiler )

```
data =   [ {"email":"admin@yopmail.com",

        "data": [
            {"content_title": "1", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": "audio"},

            {"content_title": "2", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""},

            {"content_title": "3", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""}
        ]
    }
]

def is_data_valid( data ):
    return 'content_title' in data and data['content_title'] is not '' \
        and 'content_type' in data and data['content_type'] is not '' \
        and 'content_status' in data and data['content_status'] is not ''

invalid_data = []
valid_data = []

for i in data:
    for idx, data in enumerate( i['data'] ):
        if is_data_valid( data ):
            valid_data.append( data )
        else:
            invalid_data.append( data )

print( valid_data )
print( invalid_data )
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem seems to be incorrect usage of the data structure. The array and dictionary elements seem to be getting intermingled in the code that reads the structure.

You don't need to use a `flag` variable to control flow. Too many conditions will only confuse you when it comes to debugging. Instead, move all validations to a separate function, and keep adding more as you grow. The separate function should either return True or False after evaluating all conditions.

Also, you don't have to use enumerate. You don't need to loop with an index.

Here's a very simple solution:

```
initial_data = [
    {
        "email": "admin@yopmail.com",
        "data": [
                {"content_title": "1", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": "audio"},
                {"content_title": "2", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""},
                {"content_title": "3", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""},
                {"content_title": "", "content_status": "Available", "content_type": ""}]
    }]

emailID = initial_data[0]['email']
data = initial_data[0]['data']

validData = []
invalidData = []


def is_valid(data_item):
    return (data_item.get('content_title', "") and
            data_item.get('content_type', "").capitalize() in ['Audio', 'Video'])


if emailID is not None:
    flag = True
    for value in data:
        if is_valid(value):
            validData.append(value)
        else:
            invalidData.append(value)

print(validData)
print(invalidData)
```